# Why do I have to use return in a map closure in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm super new in React Js and I'm confusing in map method in react component. I'm making movie list app using react, and declared array of Object named movies. I wanted to use map method to pass props to child component.

But, when I compiled without return() in map method, I got error like this.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movie from './Movie.js';


const movies = [
    {
        title:"Oldboy",
        poster:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/bb/Oldboy_2013_film_poster.jpg/220px-Oldboy_2013_film_poster.jpg"
    },
    {
        title:"Matrix",
        poster:"http://www.whatisthematrix.com/img/matrix.jpg"
    },
    {
        title:"Full Metal Jacket",
        poster:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MN0ANVJTL._SY445_.jpg"
    },
    {
        title:"Hunger Game",
        poster:"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA4NDg3NzYxMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTgyNzkyNw@@._V1_.jpg"
    }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {movies.map(movie => {
            <Movie title= {movie.title} poster={movie.poster}/>
        })};
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But, When I compiled it with return() in map method, it runned successfully. As I know, there is no need to use return in ES6. Can you tell me why this error occured?

Comment: *"there is no need to use return in ES6"* ... not really true. There is ability for implicit return or explicit return depending on syntax used. Do some more reading on how arrow functions work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a need to use `return` with ES6 arrow functions, otherwise it would be impossible for them to not return anything.

`return` keyword can be omitted with *implicit return* with no braces:

```
movies.map(movie => <Movie title= {movie.title} poster={movie.poster}/>)
```

Parentheses can be used for readability:

```
movies.map(movie => (
    <Movie title= {movie.title} poster={movie.poster}/>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Implicit return works only if there is no block `{}`

when you use `{}` after arrow you need to use return

`{movies.map(movie => {
    <Movie title= {movie.title} poster={movie.poster}/>
 })};`

Or you can do it using `()`

```
{movies.map(movie => (
   <Movie title= {movie.title} poster={movie.poster}/>
 ))};
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 if a function has to return only value than you can write like this:

```
{
  movies.map((item) => <Movies title={item.title} poster={item.poster}/>); 
}
```

If a function has more task to do you can use like this:

```
{
  movies.map((item) => {
    return(
      <Movies title={item.title} poster={item.poster}/>
    );
  }); 
}
```